# CDO:NetCDF: Numeric conversion not representable

Tags: cdo-climate

I am trying to merge the following files in cdo:
1979-1982.nc  1983-1995.nc  1996-2008.nc  2009-2021.nc that each contain one variable (the same in all files). I use the code: `cdo mergetime *.nc merged_file.nc` but I get the error: NetCDF: Numeric conversion not representable. Any idea?

Comment: Any chance to add link to a data file?

Comment: They are means sea level pressure data from ERA5 for the whole North Atlantic.

Answer (score 0):

[Does this post help?](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/588)

In their case it was the presence of "inf" that caused issues.

they suggest resolving this with

```
cdo setctomiss,inf
```

As Robert says in his comment, packing can cause issues, try also adding the option

```
-b f32
```

Comment: Also possible it's caused by the raw data being packed: https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Cdo#netCDF-with-packed-data. By coincidence I'm trying to solve the exact same error, but there is no clear cause of the error....

Comment: Yes, try converting to float. I usually find I have to do that when combining packed data files in any way

Comment: They are means sea level pressure data from ERA5 for the whole North Atlantic.

Comment: Then almost certain that Robert is right, very likely packing. Will update my answer but should actually be Robert that gets the credit

Comment: Most of the ERA5 data I have dealt with is stored as integer with an offset, so you probably want to convert to float "cdo -b F64 -mergetime infile outfile". I was working with ERA5 shortwave radiation recently and had to do exactly this